Existence of negative fixed points for power series with non-negative coefficients
Suppose $f(x) = \sum_{k=0} c_k x^k$ with $c_k\ge 0$ for all $k,$ and satisfying $f(1) = 1.$ Furthermore, $f(x)$ is not a linear function, i.e., $c_k\neq 0$ for some $k\ge 2/$ Thus, we know that for $x\in[-1,1]$ We can conclude $|f(x)|\le 1.$
Question: Are there any negative fixed points $-1 < x^* < 0$, satisfying $f(x^*) = x^*$?
The first non-triviality here refers to the condition $-1 < x^*,$ because we can easily find $f(x) =x$ or any odd monomial that obeys $f(-1) = -1$. The second trivial solution is $f(x) = x$ where every $x\in [-1,1]$ is a fixed point, but that is ruled out in the assumption that $f$ cannot be only a linear map.
My guess is that there is no such fixed points but I cannot prove it. It's rather easy to see that any non-negative fixed-points $x^*\in[0,1]$ ought to be unique. Because if $f(x^*) = x^*$ for $x^*\ge 0,$ based on the non-linearity and positivity of the coefficients, we can conclude the value of $f(x)$ will be below and above the identity line before and after $x^*$ in the $[0,1]$ range. But because in the negative range $x\in[-1,0]$, sign of $x^k$ can flip depending on $k$, it's much harder to see if there could be fixed points besides $-1$ or not.

The answer is ultimately No and it is a straightforward consequence of complex analysis.  With $D$ denoting the (open) unit disc, we have analytic $f:D\longrightarrow D$
(a.) $c_0=0\implies 0$ is the only fixed point in $D$ per Schwarz Lemma.
(b.) $c_0\in \big(0,1\big)$
note: $c_0\geq 1\implies f(z)=1$ per Max Modulus Theorem (or Parseval) which is impossible
$h(z):= f(z) -z \text{ and }h_{m}(z):= \frac{m}{m+1}\cdot f(z) -z$
$h_m$ has at most one root in $D$ for all $m$ per Schwarz's Lemma, fixed points question [alternatively this is implied by Rouche].  Further $h_m(0)\gt 0$ and $h_m(1)\lt 0$ so $h_m(w_m) =0$ for some $w_m\in \big(0,1\big)$ per Intermediate Value Theorem. $\big[$Abel's Theorem is expedient to justify this since it implies left continuity of $h$ at $1$; more basically, triangle inequality and OP's own observations tell us $\big\vert \frac{m}{m+1}\cdot f(D)\big \vert \leq \frac{m}{m+1}$ so for $\frac{m}{m+1}\lt \vert z\vert \lt 1$ we have $\big\vert z \big\vert \gt \big\vert \frac{m}{m+1}\cdot f(z)\big \vert$ which implies (i.) the aforementioned Rouche argument and (ii.) $h_m(z')\lt 0$ for $z' \in \Big(\frac{m}{m+1}, 1\Big)$ and an Intermediate Value Theorem argument using $h_m(0)$ and $h_m(z')\big]$.
Now suppose for contradiction that $f(w')=w'$ for some $w' \in \big(-1,0\big)$.  Then by principle of isolated zeros $h$ is non-zero on some punctured closed ball $\overline B\big(w', \delta\big)-\big\{w'\}$ for small enough $\delta \gt 0$ (implicitly this also means  $\vert w'\vert \gt  \delta$).  Conclude $h$ has a zero in $B\big(w', \delta\big)$ and $h_{m}$ has no zeros in $B\big(w', \delta\big)$ for all $m$ which contradicts Hurwitz's Theorem.
